# How to store raster with geospatial information in hdf5 format?

Tags: python-3.x, raster, h5py, rasterio, hdf

I would like to store many PRISM rasters in hdf5 format using h5py in python but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to get the coordinate reference systems stored so that a GIS software like ARCGIS or QGIS or other python modules (RasterIO) can read the file and know where it exists in space.

Basically I'm trying to follow the structure of how MODIS data is stored which is HDF4 but in hdf5 and with h5py.

```
precip_path = os.path.join(wrk_dir,"prism_data","Yearly_PRISM_PRCP_Clipped_1961_2021","*" )

# Get list of precip rasters

precip_list = sorted(glob(precip_path))


# Open on raster and get all needed information
   
raster_ds = rxr.open_rasterio(precip_list[0]).squeeze()
ds_size = raster_ds.shape
ds_name = os.path.basename(precip_list[0])[:-4]
x_dims = raster_ds.coords['x'].values
y_dims = raster_ds.coords['y'].values

# # Get georeference information
crs = raster_ds.rio.crs
crs
# # # Create Groups 

hf.close()
hf = h5py.File("precip_hdf.h5",'w')
grp = hf.create_group("PRISM_PRCP")

# Create datasets that contain the x and y coordinates of the prism dataset
x_coords = grp.create_dataset("x_coords",data=x_dims)
y_coords = grp.create_dataset("y_coords", data=y_dims)

dset = grp.create_dataset(ds_name, data=raster_ds)
grp[ds_name].dims[0].label = 'x'
grp[ds_name].dims[1].label = 'y'
x_coords.make_scale('x')
y_coords.make_scale('y')

# Attach a scale to the dimensions of the prism dataset
grp[ds_name].dims[0].attach_scale(grp['x_coords'])
grp[ds_name].dims[1].attach_scale(grp['y_coords'])
grp.values
hf.close()
```

When I ran the above code all the information is stored and I can view the raster in HDFview and see all the groups with spatial information but when I try to open this file in GIS software it doesn't recognize the spatial information. I'm guessing there is a bit of code that does this but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I would lookin to using [`xarray`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/index.html) to write to HDF and [`rioxarray`](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/) to handle all of the geospatial definitions.  If you have a multifile dataset, [xarray.open_mfdataset](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html) is useful.  To write out the spatial reference, check out [rio.write_crs](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.rioxarray.XRasterBase.write_crs).  I think QGIS is looking for [CF compliant metadata](https://cfconventions.org/)

Comment: too many undefined variables in the given code:  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example